# Loop through Object within Array within Object on Ajax Success

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, laravel, ajaxform

I'm submitting data to my Laravel Controller, and I'm trying to access the returned Json response.

I'm submitting the data with the following:

```
$.ajax({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
  type: "post",
  data: {ingredients: step_ingredients, description: step_description},
  dataType:'json',
  url: "{{ route('steps.store', ['id' => $recipe->id]) }}",

  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    //alert(data.desc);
    $("#ajaxOutput").html('<code>Description output: '+data.desc+'</code>');
    // $.each(data, function (key, value) {                     
    //   alert(data.ing.ingredient_id);
    // });           
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    console.warn(xhr.responseText);
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
});
```

And (for now) the controller is doing the following:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

  $data = [
    'success' => true,
    'message'=> 'Your AJAX processed correctly',
    'ing' => json_decode($request->ingredients),
    'desc' => $request->description
  ] ;

  return response()->json($data);
}
```

[image: Console Log of data response]

I can access the description etc using `data.desc` but I'm having trouble looping through the `data.ing` array, and accessing the relevant values, eg **ingredient 1 name**, or **ingredient 2 quantity**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try 
for laravel
`foreach($ing as $data) {
   echo "$data->ingredient_name"; //$data is object
}`

for javascript

`$.each(data.ing, function (key, value) { console.log(value.ingredient_name); })`

Comment: I've used the following:     `$.each(data.ing as $data) {
      console.log($data->ingredient_name); //$data is object
    };` and a few iterations of it, and keep getting "Unexpected identifier 'as'. Expected ')' to end an argument list."

Comment: try `$.each(data.ing, function (key, value) {
    console.log(value-> ingredient_name);
});`

Comment: I had to change it to `value.ingredient_name`, but that's working. Thanks!